# I just setup laravel project in my local system but getting this error on my leads page

Tags: mysql

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION migrate1_mgw3.json_extract does not exist (SQL: select * from `users` where (json_extract(`permissions`, '$."view-leads"') = true or exists (select * from `roles` where `users`.`role_id` = `roles`.`id` and json_extract(`permissions`, '$."view-leads"') = true)) and `is_activated` = 1 and `has_access` = 1 and `id` != 32 order by `display_name` asc)

I just setup this project to local system other things working fine but one page has this issue please help me.

Comment: What MySQL version are you running (`select version();`)?